# subst for-loop element in makefile?

Tags: makefile

Suppose my Makefile is as following:

```
FILES = hello.py
PHONY: hi
hi:
    -@for file in $(FILES); do \
            (echo $$file; \
            echo $(subst py,xml,$$file); \
            echo $(subst py,xml,hello.py)); \
    done
```

When make is called, the following will be printed:

```
hello.py
hello.py
hello.xml
```

May I know why echo $(subst py,xml,$$file); doesn't work the way I want it to (echoing hello.xml instead of hello.ph)?
Also, would you please let me know if you have any suggestions as to how I could modify this for-loop element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that Make expands the $(subst...) to generate text that it then passes to the shell, and you are trying to do a substitution based on the text that the shell will generate when it expands "$file".  An easy way to handle this is to do all the expansion in the shell:

```
FILES = hello.py
PHONY: hi
hi:
    -@for file in $(FILES); do \
            echo $$file; \
            echo $${file%py}xml; \
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` command might help

```
FILES = hello.py hello2.py hello3.py
PHONY: hi
hi:
    $(foreach file,$(FILES),echo $(subst py,xml,$(file));)
```

output

```
echo hello.xml; echo hello2.xml; echo hello3.xml;
hello.xml
hello2.xml
hello3.xml
```